# how to implement the search functionality using json and Ajax

Tags: json, ajax

I am new to the json and AJAX.,.
 I am working so that i can gain knowledge. I want to make search function which help to search being case insensitive and want to append in table.  This is the code that i have written and i amnot being able to figure out the problem. 
**HTML**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>JSON and AJAX.</title>
            <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
            <script src="Scripts/ajax.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="search"/>
                <button id="btnSearch">Search<`enter code here`/button>
            </form>
            <table id="showDetail">
                <tr>Title  </tr>
                <tr>ISBN</tr>
                <tr>Author</tr>
                <tr>Tags</tr>
            </table>

        </body>
        </html>
```

This is the json file from which i want to search :-
**JSON**

```
    "exist": "true",
      "data": [
        {
          "Title": "HTMl and CSS: Design and Build Websites",
          "ISBN": "978-1118008188",
          "First Name": "Jon",
          "Last Name": "Duckett",
          "Tags": [ "CSS", "Web", "Design", "Programming" ]
        },
        {
          "Title": "Beginning Programming All-In-One Desk Reference For Dummies",
          "ISBN": "978-0470108543",
          "First Name": "Wallace",
          "Last Name": "Wang",
          "Tags": [ "Introductory", "Beginning", "Programming", "Languages", "Software" ]
        }
    ]
```

This is the javascript code where i define the search function.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("btnSearch").click(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Data/books.json",
                success: function (detail) {
                    var td = $("#showDetail");
                    var textdisplay = $("#search").val();

                    if (detail.exist === "true") {
                        td.empty();

                        for (var i = 0; i < detail.data.length; i++) {
                            var oo = detail.data[i];
                            if (oo.text.indexOf(textdisplay) > -1) {
                                var add = $("<tr></tr>").text(oo.text);
                                td.append(add)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            })
        });
    });
```

This is the code that i have written so that i can search from the json file which is in Data folder. My main problem is i am not being able to figure out the problem not appending on table. Hope you guys will help me.

Answer (score 0):

-the best way to make your search general and to manage to customize it later you should make a request to a php file which will handle the search then the return json array of matches then using jquery you should display this values in your table.
-we are going to pass the searching values to **search.php** using get and in search.php file we will extract those values.
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JSON and AJAX.</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="searchTitle"/>
    <a id="btnSearch">Search</a>
</form>
<table id="showDetail" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>ISBN</th> 
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Tags</th>
    </tr>


</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        $("#btnSearch").on('click', function (e) {
            var Title = $('#searchTitle').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "search.php?Title="+Title,
                success: function (data) {
                   data = JSON.parse(data);
                   for(var i = 0 ; i< data.length ; i++)
                   {
                        var content = "<tr><th>"+ data[i]['Title'] +"</th><th>" + data[i]['ISBN'] + "</th><th>"+ data[i]['First Name']  + data[i]['Last Name'] +"</th><th>"+ data[i]['Tags'].toString() +"</th></tr>";
                        $('#showDetail').append(content);
                   }
                }

            });
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**search.php**

```
<?php 

    $content = json_decode( file_get_contents('books.json'), true );
    $title = strtolower($_GET['Title']);

    $matches = [];
    foreach($content['data'] as $index => $data)
    {
        $pos = strpos( strtolower($data['Title']) , $title);

        if( $pos !== false)
        {
            $matches[] = $data;
        }

    }
    die(json_encode( $matches ));
?>
```